# PHP: Do not create a row if it already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a row only if one doesn't already exist. I'm trying to check if a row exists with the same `steamid`, If it exists, do nothing. Otherwise create the row.

Using the following code creates a row everytime I refresh the page.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM Main WHERE steamid = ".$steamprofile[steamid];
//$sql = "SELECT setup FROM Main WHERE steamid = $steamprofile[steamid]";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    steamlogin(); //login button

}  else {

    include ('../core-auth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if (($row["setup"]) == 1){
                        echo "<br><div class='container'><div class='jumbotron'><div align='center'>";
                        echo "<h4>You have already Setup your account!</h4><br>";
                        echo "<a href='../index.php' class='btn btn-success btn-block' role='button'><span class='  glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span>  Back</a>";
                        exit;

        }

}  

    } else {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO Main (steamname, steamid, warns, notifi, setup)
VALUES ('$steamprofile[personaname]', '$steamprofile[steamid]', '0', '0', '1')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Added user account.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}   
    }
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: There are missing quotes in `$sql    = "SELECT * FROM Main WHERE steamid = ".$steamprofile[steamid];`... It should be `$steamprofile['steamid']`

Comment: and where is this coming from? `$steamprofile[steamid]`

Comment: There is the `insert into tbl .... on duplicate key update field=val ` statement with mysql which might be of interest

Comment: The quotes issue made no difference :(

Comment: too many unknowns here. someone gave you answer below, ask them

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add single quotes to the array variables. Please try the following updated code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM Main WHERE steamid = ".$steamprofile['steamid'];
//$sql = "SELECT setup FROM Main WHERE steamid = $steamprofile[steamid]";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    steamlogin(); //login button

}  else {

    include ('../core-auth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if (($row["setup"]) == 1){
                        echo "<br><div class='container'><div class='jumbotron'><div align='center'>";
                        echo "<h4>You have already Setup your account!</h4><br>";
                        echo "<a href='../index.php' class='btn btn-success btn-block' role='button'><span class='  glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span>  Back</a>";
                        exit;

        }

}  

    } else {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO Main (steamname, steamid, warns, notifi, setup)
VALUES ('".$steamprofile['personaname']."', '".$steamprofile['steamid']."', '0', '0', '1')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Added user account.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}   
    }
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks so much! The following code didnt help me :(. It still creates a row when another is created with the same steamid

Comment: Please try putting session_start(); at the top of the code

Comment: @DevendraSoni what do you think I asked them [17 mins. ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883661/php-do-not-create-a-row-if-it-already-exists#comment57505045_34883661) *prior to my comment here*, amongst another question but gotten no response.

Comment: @Fred Sorry I totally missed it...

Comment: @DevendraSoni it's not you who needed to see that, it's the OP ;-)

Comment: @DevendraSoni Did not work, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Im sorry mate, Im getting flooded atm.

Comment: For the first time login, Have you set the SESSION: $_SESSION['steamid']